# "sort -nu" on uuids

Tags: sort, uuid

anyone could explain why "sort -nu" returns only 1 unique line in example below?

```
$ cat /tmp/test_
1e971713-31e4-62d0-a3d1-37c0610c10e5
1e97d59f-bc32-6126-b7b1-0b52ddd35273
1e971713-31e4-62d0-a3d1-37c0610c10e5
$ sort -nu /tmp/test_
1e971713-31e4-62d0-a3d1-37c0610c10e5
$
```

shouldn't there be two unique lines on output like on "sort -u"?

```
$ sort -u /tmp/test_
1e971713-31e4-62d0-a3d1-37c0610c10e5
1e97d59f-bc32-6126-b7b1-0b52ddd35273
$
```

Comment: Why are you using `-n` to sort non-numerical data? I'm assuming it stops comparing after the initial `1` (no more digits) and since all lines starts with `1`, there is only one "unique" key.  Can't say this is what happens for certain, but it behaves like it.

Comment: @Kusalananda that certainly seems to be the case for the GNU implementation (as one can verify by adding the `--debug` option)

Comment: @steeldriver BSD `sort` on OpenBSD behaves the same, although `--debug` there shows the whole line as the key. I'm assuming it then uses `strtol()` to convert the keys to integers, which would return the initial `1` only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@Kusalananda is right.

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html

> The commands `sort -u` and `sort | uniq` are equivalent, but this
>   equivalence does not extend to arbitrary sort options. For example,
>   `sort -n -u` inspects only the value of the initial numeric string
>   when checking for uniqueness, whereas `sort -n | uniq` inspects the
>   entire line.

As your numeric string is `1`, you only get the first line.